# How to modify array using multiple conditions in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, conditional-statements

Im started to study Ruby today and i don't understand yet how to modify a array with multiple conditions, I had search about this and reading documentantion but just found with one condition.

I tried map, filter_map, for in, and others methods but i dont know what a doing wrong. I do this test:

```rb
def test_fuzz_buzz
    input = [2, 15, 7, 9, 45]
    expected_output = ["bug!", "fizzBuzz", "bug!", "fizz", "fizzBuzz"]

    assert_equal expected_output, Challenges.fizz_buzz(input)

    input = [7, 9]
    expected_output = ['bug!', 'fizz']

    assert_equal expected_output, Challenges.fizz_buzz(input)

    input = [9, 25]
    expected_output = ['fizz', 'buzz']

    assert_equal expected_output, Challenges.fizz_buzz(input)
  end
```

My objective is replace 3 multiples by fizz, 5 multiples by buzz else replace by bug!

```rb
 def fizz_buzz(numbers_arr)
    # numbers_arr.each { |number|
    #   number = 'fizz' if number % 3 === 0
    #   number = 'buzz' if number % 5 === 0
    #   number = 'bug!' if number != 'fuzz' || 'buzz'
    # }

    # numbers_arr.map { |number|
    #   number = 'fizz' if number % 3 === 0
    #   number = 'buzz' if number % 5 === 0
    #   number = 'bug!' if number != 'fuzz' || 'buzz'
    # }

    numbers_arr.filter_map { |number|
      number = 'fizz' if number % 3 === 0
      number = 'buzz' if number % 5 === 0
      # number = 'bug!' if number != 'fuzz' || 'buzz'
    }

    numbers_arr.select { |number| number % 3 === 0 }.map { |number| number ='fizz' }
  end
```

Comment: Your expected output does not match the specification. `15` and `45` are divisible by `3` and `5`, so they should be replaced by either `'fizz'` or `'buzz'` (the specification is unclear about that, so you could choose either) but nowhere in the specification does it say they should be replaced by `'fizzBuzz'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that that's *not* how `#map` and its ilk work. They map an `Enumerable` object to the last expression evaluated in the block they're passed.  This can *look* like it works because in the below, the expression `x = 5` evaluates to `5`.

```
irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3].map { |x| x = 5 }
=> [5, 5, 5]
```

But, if we put a condition on that last expression, we see that it's not doing what you expect.

```
irb(main):002:0> [1,2,3].map { |x| x = 5 if x == 2 }
=> [nil, 5, nil]
```

You would expect `[1,5,3]` but because the condition isn't met for the first and last elements, that expression evaluates to `nil`.

Using a conditional expression as the last element can work, though.

```
def fizz_buzz(nums)
  nums.map do |n|
    if n % 15 == 0
      "fizzBuzz"
    elsif n % 5 == 0
      "Buzz"
    elsif n % 3 == 0
      "fizz"
    else
      "bug!"
    end
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):016:0> fizz_buzz [2, 15, 7, 9, 45]
=> ["bug!", "fizzBuzz", "bug!", "fizz", "fizzBuzz"]
```